# Fitting text into the Events of Primefaces Extensions' Timeline

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

The problem is, that I want to fit the text into the box-event of the timeline. How can I set this?

```
<p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
    <pe:timeline id="timeline" value="#{pageController.tt.timelines}" eventStyle="box"
                         height="600px" width="100%" axisPosition="top"  widgetVar="timelineWidget">                            
    <p:ajax listener="#{pageController.tt.onEventSelect}"  event="eventSelect" 
                        update="mainpanel, locations, rooms, timeFrom, timeTo, colorpicker"/>
    </pe:timeline>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

How do I implement the behavior, that the text font size is reduced according to the amount of text or linebreaks are automatically done?